# Merge Conflict Even There is No Conflict at Jenkins Groovy

Tags: git, jenkins, github, groovy

I have below groovy script to merge a branch into another branch:

```
git branch: 'master', url: 'https://enterprise_git_url/coverity-jenkins-test.git',  credentialsId: 'temp_functional_sso'

sh 'git checkout coverity'
sh 'git tag -a tagName -m "Merge Master into Coverity"'
sh 'git merge master'
sh 'git commit -am "Merged master branch to coverity'
sh "git push origin coverity"
```

But it gives below error even I can merge it via git bash:

```
+ git merge master
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the merge conflict?  The most likely problem is that
you do different steps and there actually is a merge conflict.  Why else
would jenkins/groovy influence the outcome?

Comment: @cfrick I newly create coverity branch from master and there is no conflict, also there is no problem with git bash or etc.